# Provide default Angular i18n translation from packaged component library

Tags: angular, internationalization

We want to build up a component library with Angular. The component library will live as a dependency which can be pulled from npm. In this component library we need translations. We would like to go with the standard i18n solution from Angular.

My question is: Is it possible to provide default translations for e.g. english, german, spanish from the library itself and still let the developers using this component library in their app add more translations to it?

I wonder how would you handle a language switch if you want to use the default translations from the library?